# Python: how to access list of dictionary and matching the value of key element

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionary like this, I want to loop through all the "message" value and then if the value match  "App init" , then i will sys.exit(0) if the "message" value match "Error" I will sys.Exit(1).

But the problem is I don't see  the code match the( log[index]['message'] in 'App init') conditon since I don't see the printout "haha The application is running".

I am new in python, can someone tell me what went wrong? I have been googling for some time, and trying different approach, but it doesn't work.....

```
log =    [{'timestamp': 1666791137689, 'level': 'ALL', 'message': '10-26 14:54:33.389  7768  7793 D EGL_emulation: app_time_stats: avg=16.67ms min=15.85ms max=17.49ms count=60'}, 
    {'timestamp': 1666791137689, 'level': 'ALL', 'message': '10-26 14:54:34.390  7768  7793 D EGL_emulation: app_time_stats: avg=15.44ms min=14.40ms max=16.90ms count=60'}, 
    {'timestamp': 1666791137689, 'level': 'ALL', 'message': '10-26 14:54:35.406  7768  7793 D EGL_emulation: app_time_stats: avg=15.54ms min=11.85ms max=17.15ms count=61'}, 
    {'timestamp': 1666791137689, 'level': 'ALL', 'message': '10-26 14:54:35.654   218  7685 I keystore2: keystore2::watchdog: Watchdog thread idle -> terminating. Have a great day.'},     
    {'timestamp': 1666791137689, 'level': 'ALL', 'message': '10-29 05:04:01.873 Default [Info ] App init'}]

message_list = []
for index in range(len(log)):
        message_list.append(log[index]['message'])
        print(log[index]['message'])

        if(log[index]['message'] in 'App init'):
            print("haha The application is running" + log[index]['message'])
            sys.exit(0)
        elif(log[index]['message'] in 'ERROR'):
            print("haha The application is having ERROR" + log[index]['message'])
            sys.exit(1)

with open('message_log.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(str(message_list))
```

Comment: `log[index]['message'] in 'App init'` should be reversed: `'App init' in log[index]['message']`. The same for `ERROR`

Answer (score 0):

log[index]['message'] in 'App init' should be reversed: 'App init' in log[index]['message']. The same for ERROR